# Using <script> inside a jQuery-template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I'm using jQuery-templates for the first time, and I need my template to include some javascript, so it it run when the template is rendered.
I need at timestamp for the current time...

Writing

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in a template, renders it to fail.

Is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 0):

### the following was blatantly copied from my [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651327/correct-syntax-for-javascript-src-declaration/7651356#7651356)

When the HTML parser finds `<script>` it will start parsing the contents until it finds `</script>` which is present in:

```
document.write("<script src='links7.js?'+Math.random()+></script>
```

As such, you'll need to change the source so that it's not parsed as the end of a script element:

```
document.write("<script src='links7.js?'+Math.random()+></scri" + "pt>");
```

Ideally, you'd have HTML escaped all your inline JavaScript code, which would also mitigate this issue:

```
document.write(&quot;&lt;script src='links7.js?'+Math.random()+&gt;&lt;/script&
```

---

For your particular case (which is different enough for me to not mark as a dupe), make sure that your content between your `script` tags is HTML escaped, or correctly placed between `<![CDATA[ ]]>` tags.

```
&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```

-or-

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
/* ]]> */
```

---

That all being said, you should be calling the necessary JS during the rendering process, and not injecting a `script` element into the DOM unnecessarily.

Comment: @Smet, i can't help you further until you post some code that shows what you're trying to do in JS.